# postgresql: How to calculate the cost of an index scan？

Tags: postgresql

```
set cpu_tuple_cost=0.01;  
set cpu_index_tuple_cost = 0.005;  
set cpu_operator_cost = 0.0025;  
set seq_page_cost= 1.0;  
set random_page_cost = 4.0; 

set session enable_seqscan = off;
explain (analyze,verbose,costs,buffers,timing)select c_bh,c_xzdm,c_jgid,c_ajbm from t_test where d_slrq >='2018-03-18'

Bitmap Heap Scan on db.t_test  (cost=4.17..10.31 rows=3 width=96) (actual time=0.033..0.039 rows=5 loops=1)
  Output: c_bh, c_xzdm, c_jgid, c_ajbm
  Recheck Cond: (t_test.d_slrq >= '2018-03-18'::date)
  Heap Blocks: exact=2
  Buffers: shared hit=3
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_ttjaj_dslrq  (cost=0.00..4.17 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=6 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (t_test.d_slrq >= '2018-03-18'::date)
        Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning time: 0.265 ms
Execution time: 0.079 ms

db_jcxx=# select relpages,reltuples from pg_class where relname ='t_test';
 relpages | reltuples 
----------+-----------
        7 |       141

db_jcxx=# select relpages,reltuples from pg_class where relname ='idx_ttjaj_dslrq';
 relpages | reltuples 
----------+-----------
        2 |       141
```

The final cost = 10.31 is how to calculate?
Don't know what I also need to provide more information?

Comment: Do you want the complete detailed configuration? Then get the source code and good luck it is quite complex. Or do you just want to know which settings influence the outcome in what way?

Comment: I want to through the formula to calculate the costhttps://blog.csdn.net/fly2nn/article/details/61924344